# How to include constant string values to reduced values (Crossfilter and Reductio)

Tags: javascript, crossfilter, reductio

**Given a data that looks like:**

```
data = [
    {   
        "partner": "ABCD",
        "category": "CORTICOSTERIODS",
        "name": "NP Slow Meedrol Methylprednisolone Sodium Succinate Injection USP 500mg x 1 Vial",
        "price_sum": 22288.00,
        "qty_sum": 50.00000000000000000
    },
    {
        "partner": "ABCD",
        "category": "MEDICAL DISPOSABLE",
        "name": "4 INCH CAST FIBREGLASS",
        "price_sum": 135324.00,
        "qty_sum": 63.00000000000000000
    },
    {
        "partner": "ABCD",
        "category": "DERMATOLOGICALS",
        "name": "ABF CREAM 20G",
        "price_sum": 150169.29,
        "qty_sum": 150.00000000000000000
    },
    {   
        "partner": "CDEF",
        "category": "CORTICOSTERIODS",
        "name": "NP Slow Meedrol Methylprednisolone Sodium Succinate Injection USP 500mg x 1 Vial",
        "price_sum": 22288.00,
        "qty_sum": 50.00000000000000000
    },
    {
        "partner": "CDEF",
        "category": "MEDICAL DISPOSABLE",
        "name": "4 INCH CAST FIBREGLASS",
        "price_sum": 135324.00,
        "qty_sum": 63.00000000000000000
    }
]
```

I would like to add the category of the keys to the values when grouped by names alongside the sum of prices and qtys for further processing. With the help of `crossfilter` and `reductio`, I got what is consumable by other functions, just that I couldn't figure out how to add the category of each of the keys to it.

**What I am currently using:**

```
function categ_tab(data){
    // The needed data should be grouped by names summed up by qty and price
    // Thus crossfilter and reductio will be used to take the burden off server
    var group = crossfilter(data).dimension(function(d) { return d.name; }).group(),
        reducer = reductio();
    // sum up qty and price
    reducer.value("qty").sum(function(d) { return d.qty_sum; });
    reducer.value("price").sum(function(d) { return d.price_sum; });
    return reducer(group).all();
```

**Current Result:**

```
[
    {
        "key":"4 INCH CAST FIBREGLASS",
        "value":{
            "qty":{"sum":126},
            "price":{"sum":270648}
        }
    },
    {
        "key":"ABF CREAM 20G",
        "value":{
            "qty":{"sum":150},
            "price":{"sum":150169.29}
        }
    },
    {
        "key":"NP Slow Meedrol Methylprednisolone Sodium Succinate Injection USP 500mg x 1 Vial",
        "value":{
            "qty":{"sum":100},
            "price":{"sum":44576}
        }
    }
]
```

**Desired Result:**

```
[
    {
        "key":"4 INCH CAST FIBREGLASS",
        "value":{
            "qty":{"sum":126},
            "price":{"sum":270648},
            "category": {"iDontCare":"MEDICAL DISPOSABLE"}
        }
    },
    {
        "key":"ABF CREAM 20G",
        "value":{
            "qty":{"sum":150},
            "price":{"sum":150169.29},
            "category": {"iDontCare":"DERMATOLOGICALS"}
        }
    },
    {
        "key":"NP Slow Meedrol Methylprednisolone Sodium Succinate Injection USP 500mg x 1 Vial",
        "value":{
            "qty":{"sum":100},
            "price":{"sum":44576},
            "category": {"iDontCare":"CORTICOSTERIODS"}
        }
    }
]
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the `iDontCare` field names in your example, but if you're looking for an array of the categories for each key, it seems like [valueList](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#reductiovaluelistaccessor) should do the job.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon, `iDontCare` was just used to mean any name is okay by me. I have solved it with the valueList you referenced, I never believed it could be that cheap. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Gordon I never knew it could be this cheap, [valueList](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio#reductiovaluelistaccessor) did the trick:

```
function categ_tab(data){
    // The needed data should be grouped by names summed up by qty and price
    // Thus crossfilter and reductio will be used to take the burden off server
    var group = crossfilter(data).dimension(function(d) { return d.name; }).group(),
        reducer = reductio();
    // sum up qty and price
    reducer.value("qty").sum(function(d) { return d.qty_sum; });
    reducer.value("price").sum(function(d) { return d.price_sum; });
    reducer.value("category").valueList(function (d) { return d.category;});
    return reducer(group).all();
```

**Gives:**

```
[
    {
        "key":"4 INCH CAST FIBREGLASS",
        "value":{
            "qty":{"sum":126},
            "price":{"sum":270648},
            "category": {"valueList":["MEDICAL DISPOSABLE"]}
        }
    },
    {
        "key":"ABF CREAM 20G",
        "value":{
            "qty":{"sum":150},
            "price":{"sum":150169.29},
            "category": {"valueList":["DERMATOLOGICALS"]}
        }
    },
    {
        "key":"NP Slow Meedrol Methylprednisolone Sodium Succinate Injection USP 500mg x 1 Vial",
        "value":{
            "qty":{"sum":100},
            "price":{"sum":44576},
            "category": {"valueList":["CORTICOSTERIODS"]}
        }
    }
]
```

Thank you.